# java - how to get JVM thread priority?

Tags: java, jstack

I thought jstack was supposed to provide thread priority information but all I get is this for example...

```
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 18668: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.run() @bci=3, line=149 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 1382: (state = IN_JAVA)
 - java.nio.Bits.copyToArray(long, java.lang.Object, long, long, long) @bci=64, line=715 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
```

How do I find thread priorities?

OS: Ubuntu 10.04.4

Java 1.6.0_26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly likely it doesn't have thread priority as it is just a hint which is usually ignore. Esp if you have free CPU.

To get thread priority you can get all the threads in process and obtain the priority set. I don't believe you csn get this externally.

Comment: I dont have free cpu and I have set -XX:+UseThreadPriorities and -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 if that makes a difference.

Comment: In that case I would optimise your code or buy a bigger/more machines so you are not using 100% of your cpus all the time.

Comment: Sorry, I managed to misread your comment as "CPU at max". Its not at max, there is free CPU it fluctuates between 100% and 315%. I think the max on this machine is 800% - 8 cores.

Comment: @TedTrippin So if there is a free CPU, even the lowest priority thread will run.  Priority only matters when the scheduler has to make a choice about which threads can run and for how long.